# Custom UVGenerator - howto?

Tags: three.js

I have a use case in which users can specify texture that then is to be mapped onto an object across multiple faces. So unfortunately I cannot use standard UV mapping like with Blender and thus want to write my own custom `UVGenerator` to create my own projection.
So I am looking for detailed info how to do it.

I know that `THREE.ExtrudeGeometry.WorldUVGenerator` can serve as an example that is located in `src/extras/geometries/ExtrudeGeometry.js`

In there I found two methods where I am not sure how the work together. The first is `generateTopUV` which basically takes 3 vertices as parameters and expects that I return three pairs of u/v values. So that's pretty straight forward what the method does.

```
generateTopUV: function ( geometry, indexA, indexB, indexC )
```

The second is a odd to me since it takes four vertices and I wonder why and also the name doesn't really help me. Hope sb can shed some light on this.

It's code for WorldUVGenerator is this:

```
generateSideWallUV: function ( geometry, indexA, indexB, indexC, indexD ) {
    var vertices = geometry.vertices;

    var a = vertices[ indexA ];
    var b = vertices[ indexB ];
    var c = vertices[ indexC ];
    var d = vertices[ indexD ];

    if ( Math.abs( a.y - b.y ) < 0.01 ) {

        return [
            new THREE.Vector2( a.x, 1 - a.z ),
            new THREE.Vector2( b.x, 1 - b.z ),
            new THREE.Vector2( c.x, 1 - c.z ),
            new THREE.Vector2( d.x, 1 - d.z )
        ];

    } else {

        return [
            new THREE.Vector2( a.y, 1 - a.z ),
            new THREE.Vector2( b.y, 1 - b.z ),
            new THREE.Vector2( c.y, 1 - c.z ),
            new THREE.Vector2( d.y, 1 - d.z )
        ];

    }

}
```

Cheers Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved this by just setting geometry.faceVertexUvs with an array of arrays where the inner array contained 3 vector2's that give the uv values.

Works nicely :-) and no need to handle 4 vertices

Answer (score 0):

The three vertices in the Top and Bottom UV generation process each define one triangle.

The side wall is (separately) created as a string of rectangles, each of which is subsequently split into two coplanar triangles.  Those 4 vertices define one rectangle.

If a bevel is requested, it is part of this rectangle process.